# C++ CGAL installation for Windows with Cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, installation, cgal

I am sorry for this really stupid question, but I've no idea how to do this.

I have downloaded cygwin to execute C++ programs, which works fine. Then I downloaded the CGAL library but I have no idea where to copy it in order to work. Can you help me with this?

No matter where I tried to copy it, there always was an error that they didn't find the corresponding files. I tried to follow These instructions (http://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html#GeneralPrerequisites), so I downloaded the boost library, installed cmake, changed the path variable, but I still have no idea how to make it run.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pr40td90fz8raln/CMakeOutput.txt?dl=0) is the link to the log file.

Comment: Which compiler will you use? gcc or MSVC?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I will use gcc.

Comment: In that case, you need to install boost, gmp, mpfr and cmake in cygwin (with the cygwin installer) for example. Then run the cmake from cygwin on the CMakeList.txt at the root of the CGAL directory

Comment: Thanks for your help. I installed those. Now I have problems understanding your second step. What do you mean with that, can you explain it in more detail? (Sorry, I'm a beginner, never worked with cygwin before, so it's a little bit confusing to me)

Comment: I mean what is described [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title0)

Comment: Sorry again for the late answer. I tried to follow these steps but got an error when typing in "cmake .": Configuring incomplete, errors occured. In order to provide more infos, I added the CMakeOutput file to the question. I do not understand it and would be really thankful if you could help me with it.

Comment: The interesting part is what was displayed in the console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was written on the console (https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyg46mnqix5vg06/console.txt?dl=0). I have no idea what to do now, because I think I've downloaded everything in the cygwin downloader.

Comment: `CGAL requires MPFR to be found` is the point. You need to install MPFR dev package (using cygwin package manager or yourself)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Strange. I "installed" (or obviously only tried to) it several times. Now I reinstalled it twice, and it seems to work. But it gives a new error: 
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz3swphc2egog5w/console2.txt?dl=0)
Sorry for the stupid questions but I am not sure what to do now..

Comment: You need to check that the permission in your file system are OK. Might be that the path does not exist,

Comment: It's again strange. The paths do exist, I can change these files manually. But there is a "write-protect" on these files I cannot remove. But on another computer, there is this "write-protect" as well, I executed the same steps as you described and the configuration worked fine. So I have no idea how to change the permissions, they immediately change back (on both computers). On one it seems to be a problem, on the other it is not.

Comment: Looks like boost has not been found. Did you install it using cygwin?

Comment: yes, I installed it using cygwin on both computers. I reinstalled it but the same kind of error occurs: "could NOT find OpenGL, ZLIB", "CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND". I also downloaded boost "manually", but I have no idea where to copy it and how to install it "manually".

Comment: Do you have `/usr/include/boost/thread.hpp`? boost-thread development files must be installed.

Comment: Yes, this file exists. But I am not sure what you mean with your second sentence.

Comment: I meant that boost_thread libary and header should be available.

Comment: I think this is the case.

Comment: Clean your CGAL build dir and run again cmake adding -DBoost_DEBUG=ON to get more info on the pb with finding boost

Comment: I did this, and here are again the error messages (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfaagkrp324wdyp/console3.txt?dl=0).

Comment: OK, boost have been found correctly. Except the strange cygwin errors about `System Error: Device or resource busy`, every looks good on CGAL side. Try `cmake .` again followed by `make`. If it still does not work you'll have to look why you have such an error message in cygwin.

Comment: still the same errors, no matter what I do. And I have no clue why there's this error in cygwin.